# need the find rows with not null and are numeric (10,0)

Tags: plsql

can someone help with that.

I need to check against a column say, "COL_A" that if its not null and is numeric (10,0).

Need to check and find the rows that are not null and are numeric (10,0).

Please help

Comment: What is the current datatype of your COL_A column?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function to validate the number and use a NVL function to Null validation:


Code To function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isNumeric(strVal IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC PARALLEL_ENABLE
IS
  numericVal NUMBER;
BEGIN
  numericVal := to_number(strVal);
  RETURN 'True';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN value_error THEN
    RETURN 'False';
END isNumeric;
```

Code to call the function:

```
SELECT DECODE(isNumeric(NVL("COL_A", 'null')) = 'True', "COL_A", 0) AS "valor"
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is probably the best response. If you wanted to use SQL instead of PL/SQL, the following should work:

```
SELECT col_a
  FROM mytable
 WHERE regexp_like( col_a, '^[[:digit:]]*$' );
```

If you are using PL/SQL and need to process records in a loop:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR mycur IS
    SELECT col_a
      FROM mytable
     WHERE regexp_like(col_a, '^[[:digit:]]*$');
BEGIN
  FOR myrec IN mycur LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(col_a);
  END LOOP;
END;
```